# jquery callback specificity

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any specificity associated with event callback with jQuery. Say, I register a mousedown event callback on a div element, and also on the document. Which one would trigger if I click on the div? Does the order of registration matters? or the specificity (like css) matters?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will execute both, from inside out. Clicking in the div will fire the div event then the document. **[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78c5/1/)**

```
$(window.document).click(function(e){
    alert("doc");
});

$("div").click(function(e){
    alert("div");
});
```

You can avoid it firing other events with [`e.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/). **[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/b78c5/)**

```
$(window.document).click(function(e){
    alert("doc");
});

$("div").click(function(e){
    alert("div");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // prevents $(doc) from rising
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It will bubble up the DOM tree and call all other events of that type.

You can stop this with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

#### Your example

If you assigned the events like so...

```
$(document).mousedown(function() { alert('document'); });

$('div').mousedown(function() { alert('div'); });
```

Mouse down anywhere will trigger `document`'s handler, and get one alert dialog with *document*.

Mouse down on any `div` will trigger the `div`'s handler, and *then* bubble up the DOM all the way to `document` where it will trigger its event handler. You will get two alert dialogs; first the *div* one and then the *document* one.

Comment: so the order will be ALWAYS from the tip/node to the root, even if I register the node even (div above) after the root (document)

Comment: @bsreekanth It doesn't matter in which order they were registers, they always bubble from themselves through all ancestors until stopping on `document`.

Answer (score 2):

Both events will be triggered, first the div, and then the document click.